# VBA to Sort Items in Cell Separated by Commas

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a column of data that has months of a year separated by commas like below:

```
ColumnA
2023 June, 2023 May
2023 May
2022 December, 2022 October, 2023 January, 2023 June, 2023 March, 2023 May
```

These come in sorted by year and then name of month so they aren't in calendar order.

I need to be able to change this to Calendar month order like so:

```
ColumnA
2023 May, 2023 June
2023 May
2022 October, 2022 December, 2023 January, 2023 March, 2023 May, 2023 June
```

I need to be able to do this in VBA but I have no idea where to start. I can have a help column if needed on a separate sheet to determine the order the months should be in like so:

```
Sheet1 ColumnA
2022 October
2022 December
2023 January
2023 March
2023 May
2023 June
```

**Note:** Not all of the months of the year will be included as these are referring to campaigns we run and we only run two per quarter.

**Note2:** There will be anywhere from 50K-100K rows so a speedy solution would be best.

**Edit:** It has become apparent that the proposed codes are looking at the data quite literally how I posted in the examples. That's my fault as I was trying to simplify things. I need it to actually retain any info after the date. They will all have a YYYY Month format but they will also have some text after the date and before the comma delimiter. View below new before and after examples:

Before:

```
ColumnA
2023 May Blah Blah, 2023 June Blah Blah
2023 May Blah Blah
2022 October Blah Blah, 2022 December Blah Blah, 2023 January Blah Blah, 2023 March Blah Blah, 2023 May Blah Blah, 2023 June Blah Blah
```

After:

```
ColumnA
2023 May Blah Blah, 2023 June Blah Blah
2023 May Blah Blah
2022 October Blah Blah, 2022 December Blah Blah, 2023 January Blah Blah, 2023 March Blah Blah, 2023 May Blah Blah, 2023 June Blah Blah
```

Comment: "I was trying to simplify things" is a nice way to confuse us... Then "after the date" and "before the comma delimiter" looks to be the same thing. Do you really need help? Aren't you able even now to edit your question and show us **real examples of the data you have** and **how do you want the data to look after processing**?

Comment: @FaneDuru You're right. I'll update my post to include proper examples. I guess I deserve that downvote. I'll also test your suggested code below and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next sorting Sub:

```
Sub BubbleDateSort(arrD, Optional boolDescend As Boolean = False)
  Dim arrM: arrM = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
  Dim arr1, arr2, i As Long, j As Long, temp, mtch1, mtch2
  For i = LBound(arrD) To UBound(arrD) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arrD)
        arr1 = Split(arrD(i)): arr2 = Split(arrD(j))
        mtch1 = Application.match(arr1(1), arrM, 0)
        If IsError(mtch1) Then MsgBox arrD(i) & " has a wrong pattern...": Exit Sub
        mtch2 = Application.match(arr2(1), arrM, 0)
        If IsError(mtch1) Then MsgBox arrD(j) & " has a wrong pattern...": Exit Sub
        If boolDescend Then
            If DateValue(arr1(0) & "/" & mtch1) < DateValue(arr2(0) & "/" & mtch2) Then
                temp = arrD(i): arrD(i) = arrD(j)
                arrD(j) = temp
            End If
        Else
            If DateValue(arr1(0) & "/" & mtch1) > DateValue(arr2(0) & "/" & mtch2) Then
                temp = arrD(i): arrD(i) = arrD(j)
                arrD(j) = temp
            End If
        End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

If (firstly) can be tested selecting a cell with the comma separated dates and run the next testing sub:

```
Sub testBubbleDateSort()
  Dim arr: arr = Split(ActiveCell.value, ", ")
  BubbleDateSort arr
  Debug.Print Join(arr, "|") 'only to see in Immediate Window the resulted (sorted) array
End Sub
```

And you can use it to process all data in column "A:A":

```
Sub SortCommaSepDate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrInit, arr, sortedArr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  Set shDest = sh.Next 'use here the destination sheet you want
  
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A column
  arrInit = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
  ReDim sortedArr(1 To UBound(arrInit), 1 To 1)
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrInit)
    arr = Split(arrInit(i, 1), ", ")
    BubbleDateSort arr 'sort the resulted array
    'place the sorted array in sortedArr:
    sortedArr(i, 1) = Join(arr, ", ")
  Next i
  '
  shDest.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(sortedArr), 1).Value2 = sortedArr
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above solution should be very fast, even for large ranges, working mostly in memory and dropping the processed array at once, at the end of the code.

It **now** returns in the **next sheet**, so such an empty sheet **must exist** after the one to be processed. But, if you check the return and it fit your needs, you can return it back in the processed sheet, overwriting the existing (unsorted) data.

**Edit**:

In order to use the `BubbleDateSort` to sort descending, you should call it as:

```
  BubbleDateSort arr, True
```

The last (`Optional`) parameter makes the above mentioned sorting `Sub` sorting descendent.

In order to call it to work as you required in your initial question, you can call it as in my initial answer. Last sub parameter (`boolDescend`) is `Optional` so, if it is missing its value will be `False` and it will work as initially.

Please, send some feedback after testing it in both variants...

Comment: @DanCue Did you test the above answer? It will also correctly return (as it is) for the pattern `2022 October Scope Repeat` and `2022 December Scope Normal`. Of course, the separator must be ** `", "`, as on the example you show**! If the space after comma is missing, the code should only be adapted on the line `arr = Split(arrInit(i, 1), ", ")`!

Comment: Took 1.5 seconds to process ~40K lines and this kept the additional text after the Year and Month. Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Went ahead and accepted this answer as it had everything I needed and when I put this code inline with the other code the time was reduced to only .7 seconds! Thanks again.

Comment: One follow-up question... Is there a way to reverse the order of the array output? Instead of starting with oldest month, we start with most recent?

Comment: I just realized it's also missing September in arrM.

Comment: interesting. When I add "September" to the array I get an error at the line ```If DateValue(arr1(0) & "/" & mtch1) > DateValue(arr2(0) & "/" & mtch2) Then``` of TypeMismatch. I'm guessing because mtch1 is equal to 13 which is not a proper month? So when I delete the +1 on the ```mtch1 = Application.Match(arr1(1), arrM, 0) + 1``` I don't get an error anymore but I get blank values for the whole column.

Comment: @DanCue Ups... I missed September... I will add it and modify the sorting code to work as it should. In fact, I will adapt it to also work for reversed `Date` order.

Comment: That worked. Very useful to be able to choose between descending and ascending!

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub reorder()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As String
    Dim arData, ar, i, j, tmp
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arData = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

        ' process rows
        For r = 2 To lastrow
           
            ar = Split(arData(r, 1), ",")
            
            ' add yyyymm and sort
            For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                ar(i) = Trim(ar(i))
                ar(i) = Format(Left(ar(i),8) & " 1", "yyyymm") & ar(i)
            Next

           ' bubble sort
            For i = 0 To UBound(ar) - 1
                For j = i + 1 To UBound(ar)
                    If ar(i) > ar(j) Then
                        tmp = ar(i)
                        ar(i) = ar(j)
                        ar(j) = tmp
                    End If
                Next
             Next
             
             ' remove yyyymm
             For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                ar(i) = Mid(ar(i), 7)
             Next
            
             arData(r, 1) = Join(ar, ", ")
        Next
        ' results to sheet
        .Range("B1").Resize(lastrow) = arData
    End With
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows prcessed", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```

Comment: I found this solution to be the easiest to implement and processing for 40K lines was ~1.4 seconds. My only issue is that this requires the data to be exactly the way I presented it in my question. Not your fault, but I put the information that way to simplify things. In reality the dates look like this. ```2022 October Scope Repeat``` and ```2022 December Scope Normal```. This is why I proposed a helper column. Is there anyway to adjust your code to do what it does and disregard any text beyond that date but keep it there?

Comment: I've edited my original post to clarify that. Again, my fault.

Comment: @DanCue OK I have updated code but I can't test it at present

Comment: This gave me an issue for those months that did not have any text after the Year and Month. It cut off the month name and also aded a "1" to the year.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve the following tasks:

- Get the date parts of the string (the cell content). This is easy, just use the VBA `Split` function.
- Get a real date from your partial date parts. I have used a rather dirty function to show you the idea. It doesn't handle invalid month names and works only when the regional settings of your computer matches the month names. Real dates have the advantage that they are easy to compare
- Sort the data. As you always have only very few dates per entry, I simply used a simple quicksort.
- Create a string from sorted array. That's again easy by using the `Join`-Function

The following function can be simply used as UDF, for example put the formula `=SortStringByDate(A2)` to cell B2 (and copy it down).

```
Function SortStringByDate(s As String) As String
    Dim a() As String
    a = Split(s, ",")
            
    ' Split the pieces
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Remove Spaces
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        a(i) = Trim(a(i))
    Next
    
    ' Sort the pieces
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(a)
            If DateFromString(a(i)) > DateFromString(a(j)) Then
                Dim tmp As String
                tmp = a(i)
                a(i) = a(j)
                a(j) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    ' Glue the sorted array back to one string
    SortStringByDate = Join(a, ", ")
End Function


Function DateFromString(s As String) As Date
    ' Quick and Dirty function to create a Date from something like 2023 January
    Dim dateParts() As String
    dateParts() = Split(s, " ")
    DateFromString = CDate("01 " & dateParts(1) & " " & dateParts(0))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option but this will only work in Excel 365 or 2021 or newer as it uses `WorksheetFunction.Sort` (so I think/hope might be faster ... proof will be in your testing it though).

You need both of these procedures, the `ConvertDates` Sub is what you would run, it uses the `SortMonths` to do the sorting of dates within each cell. Code is fully commented to explain what it is doing.

It assumes the dates data is in the active Worksheet in column A from row 1 down (row 1 being a header) with no empty cells.

```
Sub ConvertDates()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, rng As Range
    ' assumes the dates data is in the active Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    ' assumes the dates data is in column A from row 1 down with no empty cells
    Set rng = wks.Range("A1:A" & wks.Range("A1").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row)
    Dim datesData As Variant, i As Long
    ' get all data from the Worksheet into an array ... operating on an array is much faster than on the Worksheet directly
    datesData = rng.Value
    ' +1 is to skip the header row
    For i = LBound(datesData) + 1 To UBound(datesData)
        ' update the text for this cell (ie this set of dates)
        datesData(i, 1) = SortMonths(CStr(datesData(i, 1)))
    Next i
    ' load the updated dates data back into the Worksheet
    rng.Value = datesData
End Sub


' sort the months for one cell
Private Function SortMonths(datesIn As String) As String
    Dim datesText As Variant
    ' split the dates based on a comma being the delimiter
    datesText = Split(datesIn, ",")
    ' convert the format of the date from using a month name to using digits for the month in the
    ' format YYYYMM ... this means we can then use WorksheetFunction.Sort to sort the dates
    Dim i As Long, dt As Date
    For i = LBound(datesText) To UBound(datesText)
        dt = CDate(datesText(i))
        datesText(i) = CStr(Year(dt)) & Format(Month(dt), "00")
    Next i
    ' do the sort
    datesText = WorksheetFunction.Sort(datesText, 1, 1, True)
    ' re-build the text for the dates using the full month name and return it to the calling code
    Dim res As String
    For i = LBound(datesText) To UBound(datesText)
        res = res & Mid$(datesText(i), 1, 4) & " " & MonthName(CLng(Mid$(datesText(i), 5)), False) & ", "
    Next i
    SortMonths = Mid$(res, 1, Len(res) - 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing in cells right of the ones to be "sorted", you could use the custom sorting option of `Sort` object

assuming:

- custom order is in Sheet1 cells A1 to A6
- cells to be "ordered" in Sheet2 column A, starting from row 1 downwards

you can use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    
    With Sheet2
        Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                Dim v As Variant
                    v = Split(cel.Value, ", ")
                    If UBound(v) > 0 Then
                        With cel.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(v) + 1)
                            .Value = v
                            SortIt .Cells
                            
                            .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 1).Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value)), ", ")
                            .ClearContents
                        End With
                    End If
            Next
    End With

SafeExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SortIt(rngToSort As Range)
    With rngToSort.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rngToSort, _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                         CustomOrder:=Join(Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A6").Value), ","), _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SetRange rngToSort
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```